# Every eigenvector generating a cyclic subspaces, which contains some generalised eigenvectors .

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Is every generalised eigenvector belongs to some cyclic subspace generated by an eigenvector
?

I think 'yes' and for JNF , this cyclic subspace be a jordan block corresponding to that generating eigenvector.

Please verify that.

Comment: The cyclic subspace generated by an eigenvector is of dimension$~1$ (just the multiples of the vector) so it contains no generalised eigenvectors that are not eigenvectors. So clearly what you claim cannot be true.

Comment: Sir, you are right. Thanks. But looking at JNF , I found every jordan block corresponding to a eigenvector is made by a cyclic subspace , then what will be its generator ? .and when operator be non-diagonalisable , then on every such block has generalised eigenvectors which are not eigenvector . Then how to proceed this idea?

Comment: I found that generator of that cyclic subspace is generalised eigenvector of highest rank of that block. Am I right?

Comment: If x_m , be the generalised eigenvector of highest rank m , corresponding to eigenvalue c . Then basis of cyclic subspace is ${x_m, (A-cI)x_m, (A-cI)^2 x_m, ............... (A-cI)^{m-1} x_m} $. Here$ (A-cI)^{m-1} x_m$ be the eigenvector.